# AWS Glue (Spark) very slow

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I've inherited some code that runs incredibly slowly on AWS Glue.

Within the job it creates a number of dynamic frames that are then joined using `spark.sql`.  Tables are read from a MySQL and Postgres db and then Glue is used to join them together to finally write another table back to Postgres.

Example (note dbs etc have been renamed and simplified as I can't paste my actual code directly)

```
jobName = args['JOB_NAME']
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(jobName, args)
    
# MySQL
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db1", table_name = "trans").toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("trans")
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db1", table_name = "types").toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("types")
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db1", table_name = "currency").toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("currency")

# DB2 (Postgres)
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "db2", table_name = "watermark").toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("watermark")

# transactions
new_transactions_df = spark.sql("[SQL CODE HERE]")

# Write to DB
conf_g = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("My DB")
url = conf_g["url"] + "/reporting"

new_transactions_df.write.option("truncate", "true").jdbc(url, "staging.transactions", properties=conf_g, mode="overwrite")
```

The [`SQL CODE HERE]` is literally a simple select statement joining the three tables together to produce an output that is then written to the staging.transactions table.

When I last ran this it only wrote 150 rows but took 9 minutes to do so.  Can somebody please point me in the direction of how to optimise this?

Additional info:

- Maximum capacity: 6
- Worker type: G.1X
- Number of workers: 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, when reading/writing data in spark using JDBC drivers,  the common issue is that the operations aren't parallelized. Here are some optimizations you might want to try:

##### Specify parallelism on read

From the code you provided it seems that all the tables data is read using one query and one spark executor.

If you use spark dataframe reader directly, you can set options `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`,  `upperBound`, `fetchSize` to read multiple partitions in parallel using multiple workers, as described in the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html#data-source-option). Example:

```
spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    #...
    .option("partitionColumn", "partition_key") \
    .option("lowerBound", "<lb>") \
    .option("upperBound", "<ub>") \
    .option("numPartitions", "<np>") \
    .option("fetchsize", "<fs>")
```

When using read partitioning, note that spark will issue multiple queries in parallel, so make sure the db engine will support it and also optimize indexes especially for the `partition_column` to avoid entire table scan.

In AWS Glue, this can be done by passing additional options using the parameter `additional_options`:

> To use a JDBC connection that performs parallel reads, you can set the
> `hashfield`, `hashexpression`, or `hashpartitions` options:

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "db1", 
    table_name = "trans", 
    additional_options = {"hashfield": "transID", "hashpartitions": "10"}
).toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("trans")
```

This is described in the Glue docs: [Reading from JDBC Tables in Parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/run-jdbc-parallel-read-job.html)

##### Using `batchsize` option when writing:

In you particular case, not sure if this can help as you write only 150 rows, but you can specify this option to improve writing performance:

```
new_transactions_df.write.format('jdbc') \
    # ...
    .option("batchsize", "10000") \
    .save()
```

##### Push down optimizations

You can also optimize reading by pushing down some query (filter, column selection) directly to the db engine instead of loading the entire table into dynamic frame then filter.

In Glue, this can be done using `push_down_predicate` parameter:

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "db1", 
    table_name = "trans", 
    push_down_predicate = "(transDate > '2021-01-01' and transStatus='OK')"
).toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("trans")
```

See [Glue programming ETL partitions pushdowns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-partitions-pushdowns)

##### Using database utilities to bulk insert / export tables

In some cases, you could consider exporting tables into files using the db engine and then reading from files. The same implies when writing, first write to file then use db bulk insert command. This could avoid the bottleneck of using Spark with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

The Glue spark cluster usually takes 10 minutes only for startup. So that time(9 minutes) seems reasonable(unless you run Glue2.0, but you didn't specify the glue version you are using).

[https://aws.amazon.com/es/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/aws-glue-version-2-featuring-10x-faster-job-start-times-1-minute-minimum-billing-duration/#:~:text=With%20Glue%20version%202.0%2C%20job,than%20a%2010%20minute%20minimum](https://aws.amazon.com/es/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/aws-glue-version-2-featuring-10x-faster-job-start-times-1-minute-minimum-billing-duration/#:%7E:text=With%20Glue%20version%202.0%2C%20job,than%20a%2010%20minute%20minimum).

Answer (score 0):

**Enable Metrics:**

AWS Glue provides Amazon CloudWatch metrics that can be used to provide information about the executors and the amount of done by each executor. You can enable CloudWatch metrics on your AWS Glue job by doing one of the following:

Using a special parameter: Add the following argument to your AWS Glue job. This parameter allows you to collect metrics for job profiling for your job run. These metrics are available on the AWS Glue console and the CloudWatch console.

```
   Key: --enable-metrics
```

Using the AWS Glue console: To enable metrics on an existing job, do the following:

1. Open the AWS Glue console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Jobs.
3. Select the job that you want to enable metrics for.
4. Choose Action, and then choose Edit job.
5. Under Monitoring options, select Job
   metrics.
6. Choose Save.

Courtesy: https://softans.com/aws-glue-etl-job-running-for-a-long-time/